# Trying to run report in CRM2011, get 'Sys is undefined'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a report in CRM2011 that is an uploaded RDL file.  When I try to run it, I get the error 'Sys is undefined'.  When I look in the Debugger for Viewer.aspx, it shows

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize
('scriptmanager','form1',
['freeportViewer$ReportViewer','',
'freeportViewer$DocMap','',
'freeportViewer$ct109$ReportArea',''],[], 
['freeportViewer$ct109$ReportControl$ct100',''],1000,
'');
```

x Sys is undefined

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is scripts hasn't been loaded yet,

When the browser goes to run that code, it’s going to expect Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager to be defined somewhere. That somewhere happens to be in the other scripts that are loaded from script tags that look like this:

Since you are using the MSCRM report Viewer.aspx I suspect either this aspx file was edited or it could be a browser issue. keep a copy of the original then try the following:

If the browser fails to load those scripts, the script engine can’t find the definition for Sys, Sys.WebForms, Sys.WebFormsPageRequestManager, and thus the error.

1. You can try moving the asp:ScriptManager after  tag inside masterpage and  block inside  in your aspx page

If you use the ASP.NET AJAX ScriptManager control to add other scripts to your page, you are protected from the similar issue as well. The ScriptManager will make sure your scripts are rendered before your UI, which forces the browser to load them before rendering your UI.

2. There is a property on ScriptManager that controls this behavior (LoadScriptsBeforeUI), so if you set that to false, you will want to employ some defensive programming :

something like :

```
function hasloaded() 
{ 
  if(typeOf(Sys) == 'undefined'){ 
    alert('Please try again. The page hasn't finished loading. try refreshing the page.'); 
     return false; 
  } else { 
     return true; 
  } 
} 

if(hasLoaded()){ 
  //work with Sys. 
}
```

3. This error we can solve by adding some code in webconfig file ... code is bellow

`<httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>`

place this code in `<system.web>`